# Когда используем "о том" всегда ли нужно использовать "что"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Правильно ли следующее предложение:

*Он сказал, что сотрудники даже не будут думать о том, соответствует ли это инструкции.*

Я думаю нужно после второй запятой добавить "что".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Думать о том, соответствует ли это инструкции" значит задаваться вопросом: "А соответствует ли это инструкции?"

"Думать о том, что это соответствует инструкции". Точно известно, что соответствует, но нужно не забывать об этом (думать об этом).

"Думать о том, что соответствует ли это инструкции" - бессмысленный набор слов.